# Setting Up WAMP Server and Notepad++ on Android Device

Tags: php, android, notepad++, wampserver

My laptop is currently being repaired and I need a way for me to be able to create/edit some PHP files in my Android tab. I use WAMP server and Notepad++ in my laptop before. Now, how can I do this in my tablet? I've searched Google Play and I can't find WAMP server. Notepad++, on the other hand, seems to be a non-programmer friendly application. Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You haven't searched hard enough. There are plenty of tutorials online for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

Try AWD - IDE for Web dev ( in android market), it works fine on my Galaxy s4 wich is android 
should word for the tablets, it may be somewhat slow tho.

edit: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.kidinov.awd&hl=nl

Comment: thanks. does it have the same www folder where I can place my test file by opening localhost via browser?

Comment: Once you start up the app you will see how it works, very simple! you can use it in your browser yes.

Comment: How about a Notepad++ like app?